# Dynamic Knockout Javascript Table with Draggable columns danvk

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a knockout dynamically created html table that I am trying to add the ability to use the draggable javascript library on from: http://www.danvk.org/wp/dragtable/

Problem is that it works great for static data, but upon receiving updates (signalR in this case), it won't apply the "draggable" functionality that is defined in the table class="draggable"

Any suggestions? I'm thinking it has something to do with knockout's rendering and somehow obtaining a reference to the rendered table and them making it draggable like the example in: https://code.google.com/p/dragtable/source/browse/trunk/dynamic.html?spec=svn13&r=13

```
<div data-bind="foreach: zones() ">

            <div data-bind="if: $parent.chosenZoneNames().indexOf(ZoneName()) > -1">

                <h3>'<span data-bind="text: ZoneName"></span>' zone has <span data-bind="text: CardHolders().length"></span> Cardholders</h3> 

                    <table class="draggable" id="ZoneMonitorTable" data-bind="afterRender: afterRender" >
                        <tr >
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>
                            <th>Date Added</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                        <tbody data-bind="foreach: CardHolders">
                        <tr >
                            <td> <span data-bind="text: CardHolderFirstName"></span></td>
                            <td><span data-bind="text: CardHolderLastName"></span></td>
                            <td> <span data-bind="text: DateAdded"></span></td>
                            <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.RemoveCardholder">Remove</a></td>
                        </tr>
                       </tbody>


                </table>

            </div>

       </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This library initializes on document load. Any changes to the HTML it had access to at document load will most likely break it's behavior.
Take a look at the project's issues on google code and you'll find a discussion regarding your exact same problem.

Comment: Can you post the link?